# Override derived functions

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm trying to find if it is possible to override derived functions in JavaScript. Let's say I have a function like this.

```
function Filter(applyCallback) {
    filterController = this;

    FilterValues = {};
}

Filter.prototype = {
   constructor: Filter,
   Reset: function() {
      FilterValues = {};
   }
}

function SearchFilter(applyCallback) {
   Filter.call(this, applyCallback);
}

SearchFilter.prototype = Object.create(Filter.prototype);

SearchFilter.prototype.constructor = SearchFilter;

/// When doing this I believe i override the entire base.Reset function
SearchFilter.prototype.Reset = function() {
   /// Call Filter.Reset()
   base.Reset();

   /// Do SearchFilter.Reset things
   FilterValues.search= "default search string";
}
```

If the code isn't clear: What I want to achieve is an upper level filter controller, which will contain all generic logic such as reset and apply, and derive from that filter controller to create more specific filter controllers which contains logic for all different filter types etc. I want to preserve the generic filter controllers behaviours.

One solution I can think of is this:

```
function Filter(applyCallback) {
    filterController = this;

    FilterValues = {};
}

Filter.prototype = {
   constructor: Filter,
   Reset: function() {
      FilterValues = {};

      if(resetFunction !== null)
         resetFunction(); /// Parent calls its unknown children, ugh..
   }
}

function SearchFilter(applyCallback) {
   Filter.call(this, applyCallback);

   resetFunction = function() {
      /// Do SearchFilter.Reset things
      FilterValues.search= "default search string";
   };
}

SearchFilter.prototype = Object.create(Filter.prototype);

SearchFilter.prototype.constructor = SearchFilter;
```

Or the other way around:

```
function Filter(applyCallback) {
    filterController = this;

    FilterValues = {};

    resetFunction = function() {
       FilterValues = {};
    };
}

Filter.prototype = {
   constructor: Filter
}

function SearchFilter(applyCallback) {
   Filter.call(this, applyCallback);
}

SearchFilter.prototype = Object.create(Filter.prototype);

SearchFilter.prototype = { 
   constructor: SearchFilter,
   Reset: function() {
      if(resetFunction !== null)
         resetFunction(); /// Invoke the generics filter reset

      FilterValues.search = "default search string";
   }
}
```

In my opinion, best practice would be to have c# equivalent of base.Function(), but as I am comlpetely new to JavaScript I'm not sure if that is possible (I bet it isn't). Anyways, do anyone have any thoughts regarding this? What is the best practice and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are several easier ways of tackling this...
but rather than thinking about your architecture, what is your prescribed API usage, given that your Interface and not your implementation is what the public (and future-you) intend to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you would access the parent constructor’s prototype by name:

```
SearchFilter.prototype.Reset = function() {
    /// Call Filter.Reset()
    Filter.prototype.Reset.call(this);

    /// Do SearchFilter.Reset things
    FilterValues.search = "default search string";
};
```

ES6’s classes let you avoid this repetition, though:

```
class SearchFilter extends Filter {
    Reset() {
        super.Reset();
        FilterValues.search = "default search string";
    }
}
```

You probably also didn’t mean to make `FilterValues` a global. `this` isn’t implicit in JavaScript.

```
function Filter(applyCallback) {
    this.filterValues = {};
}
```

And note that it’s standard style to use PascalCase for constructors only, and camelCase for everything else.

Since ES6 classes also set `constructor` for you, all together, that’s:

```
class Filter {
    constructor(applyCallback) {
        this.filterValues = {};
    }

    reset() {
        this.filterValues = {};
    }
}

class SearchFilter extends Filter {
    reset() {
        super.reset();
        this.filterValues.search = "default search string";
    }
}
```

Comment: Filter.prototype.Reset.call(this); Thats cool, I thought the SearchFilter.prototype.Reset() would render Filter.Reset useless, this is definitely the accepted answer. But, I would like to check out ES6, this is way better writing than the "normal" way. I will get back once I've tested it.

Comment: @Alex: Yeah, `Object.create()` gives you an object with the specified prototype, so when you define a property on top of it you’re not modifying the prototype.

Comment: I did the Filter.prototype.Reset.call(this); for now and it worked exactly the way I wanted. Thanks Ryan.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the extend function of jQuery:

```
var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

or

```
$.extend( object1, object2 );
```

this will merge objec2 into object1

Comment: I think jquery.merge will completely override object1.a with object2.a and thus I would not be able to invoke object1.a. This is what I understand from readin the documentation at least.